# Facebook graph-api field expansion

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I don't see any difference in the field expansion section between
https://developers.facebook.com/…/grap…/using-graph-api/v2.0
and
https://developers.facebook.com/…/grap…/using-graph-api/v2.1

However, if you try doing the following in graph explorer:

me/home?fields=name,place,with_tags,from.id,from.name

It works with 1.0 and 2.0, but fails with 2.1 and 2.2.

Error 2500
Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

In 2.1+ when you are looking for fields inside of fields you have to use curly braces instead of dot notation:

`Field{ Field1, Field2 }`

Try using:

`me/home?fields=name,place,with_tags,from{id,name}`

As you can see you can call multiple sub-fields by separating with a comma.